# Post request on base url in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I have a search box on my home page, when I click on the search button, the view does not return any results.

This is my form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'PagesController@postIndex', 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form-inline', 'id' => 'search-bar')) !!}
{{ csrf_field() }}
{{Form::select('Location', ['Kasarani','Allsoaps'], null, ['class' => 'form-control',  'placeholder' => 'Location'])}}

{{ Form::select('Size', ['Bedsitter'], null, ['class' => 'form-control',  'placeholder' => 'Size']) }}

{{Form::submit('search', array('class' => 'btn btn-success'))}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This are my routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex')->name('home.index');
Route::post('/', 'PagesController@postIndex')->name('home.post.index');
```

This is my controller:

```
public function postIndex(){

    $Location = Input::get('Location');
    $Size = Input::get('Size');

    $validator= Validator::make(
              array(
                    'Location'=>$Location,
                    'Size'=>$Size
                    ),
              array(
                    'Location'=>'required',
                    'Size'=>'required'
                )
              );
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->route('home.index')->withErrors($validator);
            // echo "fail";
          }else{
            $houses=DB::table('houses')->where('Location', $Location)->where('Size', $Size)->get();
            return View('pages.home')->withHouse($houses);
          }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: If you `dd($Location);` or `dd($Size);` inside `postIndex()` (before the redirect), do you see anything?

Comment: Can you share your view code and `houses` table structure?

Answer (score 0):

when I dd($location) I see '1'

Here is my view :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

    @section('css')
        @parent
        <!-- Custom css -->
        <link href="custom/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    @stop

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- Carousel -->
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>

              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                  <img src="{{asset('images/carousel1.jpg')}}" alt="...">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    We are commited
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="{{asset('images/carousel2.jpg')}}" alt="...">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    To ensuring
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="{{asset('images/carousel3.jpg')}}" alt="...">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    You get your house of choice
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>

              <!-- Controls -->
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <!-- End of carousel -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Houses title -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="houses-title-bar">
            <h1 class="search-title">Search for your house of choice..</h1>
            <hr id="hr-position">
              <!--   <p>
                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </p> -->
                <!-- Search bar -->
                <!-- {!! Form::open(array('url' => ' ', 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form-inline', 'id' => 'search-bar')) !!} -->
                {{Form::open(array('class'=>'form-inline', 'url'=>' ', 'id' => 'search-bar' ))}}
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    {{Form::select('Location', ['Kasarani','Allsoaps'], null, ['class' => 'form-control',  'placeholder' => 'Location'])}}

                    {{ Form::select('Size', ['Bedsitter'], null, ['class' => 'form-control',  'placeholder' => 'Size']) }}

                    {{Form::submit('search', array('class' => 'btn btn-success'))}}
                {{ Form::close() }}
                </form>
                <!-- End of search bar -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of title -->

    <!-- Houses and details -->
    <div class="row first-row">
        @foreach($house as $house)
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <img src="{{ asset('images/'.$house->Photo) }}" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center" id="view-details-button">
                    <a href="{{ url('all/'.$house->slug) }}" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-style">View details</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <!-- End of houses and details -->
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="{{URL::asset('bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.2.js')}}"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="{{URL::asset('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
@stop
```

My Houses table

id | Location | Size | Created_at | Updated_at

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out : mysteries of laravel..!..The problem was in my form, initially the select form was returning the indexes of the array. I made an associative array and now it is returning the actual location and size :

Here is my new form:

```
{!! Form::open(array(
        'class'  => 'form-inline', 
        'url'    => ' ', 
        'method' => 'post', 
        'id'     => 'search-bar' 
    )) !!}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ Form::select (
            'Location', 
            [
                'Kasarani' => 'Kasarani',
                'Allsoaps' => 'Allsoaps',
                'Juja'     => 'Juja'
            ], 
            null, 
            [
                'class'       => 'form-control',  
                'placeholder' => 'Location', 
                'required'    => ''
            ]
        ) }}
    {{ Form::select(
            'Size', 
            [
                'Bedsitter'  => 'Bed sitter', 
                'Onebedroom' => 'One Bedroom',
                'Twobedroom' => 'Two Bedroom'
            ], 
            null, 
            [
                'class'       => 'form-control',  
                'placeholder' => 'Size', 
                'required'    => ''
            ]
        ) }}
    {{ Form::submit('search', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```